# Python decorator handles default arguments of the decorated function

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I want to create a 'cache' decorator for class methods, which registers in an internal class property the result of the method for avoiding to compute it several times (and I do not want to use a simple property, computed in the `__init__`, because I am not sure to compute it even once all the time).

The first idea is to create a decorator 'cache' similar to this:

```
def cache(func):
    name = "_{:s}".format(func.__name__)
    def wrapped(obj):
        if not hasattr(obj, name) or getattr(obj, name) is None:
            print "Computing..."
            setattr(obj, name, func(obj))
        else:
            print "Already computed!"
        return getattr(obj, name)
    return wrapped

class Test:
    @cache
    def hello(self):
        return 1000 ** 5
```

Everything works fine:

```
In [121]: t = Test()

In [122]: hasattr(t, '_hello')
Out[122]: False

In [123]: t.hello()
Computing...
Out[123]: 1000000000000000

In [124]: t.hello()
Already computed!
Out[124]: 1000000000000000

In [125]: hasattr(t, '_hello')
Out[125]: True
```

Now let us say that I want to do the same thing, but when the method can be called with arguments (keyworded and/or not).
Of course, now we will store the results not in distinct properties (what would be the names?...), but in a dictionary, whose keys are composed with *args and **kwargs. Let us do it with tuples:

```
def cache(func):
    name = "_{:s}".format(func.__name__)
    def wrapped(obj, *args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(obj, name) or getattr(obj, name) is None:
            setattr(obj, name, {})
        o = getattr(obj, name)
        a = args + tuple(kwargs.items())
        if not a in o:
            print "Computing..."
            o[a] = func(obj, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print "Already computed!"
        return o[a]
    return wrapped

class Test:
    @cache
    def hello(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return 1000 * sum(args) * sum(kwargs.values())

In [137]: t = Test()

In [138]: hasattr(t, '_hello')
Out[138]: False

In [139]: t.hello()
Computing...
Out[139]: 0

In [140]: hasattr(t, '_hello')
Out[140]: True

In [141]: t.hello(3)
Computing...
Out[141]: 0

In [142]: t.hello(p=3)
Computing...
Out[142]: 0

In [143]: t.hello(4, y=23)
Computing...
Out[143]: 92000

In [144]: t._hello
Out[144]: {(): 0, (3,): 0, (4, ('y', 23)): 92000, (('p', 3),): 0}
```

Thanks to the fact that the method `items` turns a dictionary in a tuple without taking account on the order in the dictionary, it works perfectly if the keyworded arguments are not called in the same orders:

```
In [146]: t.hello(2, a=23,b=34)
Computing...
Out[146]: 114000

In [147]: t.hello(2, b=34, a=23)
Already computed!
Out[147]: 114000
```

Here is my problem: if the method has default arguments, then it doesn't work anymore:

```
class Test:
    @cache
    def hello(self, a=5):
        return 1000 * a
```

Now it does not work anymore:

```
In [155]: t = Test()

In [156]: t.hello()
Computing...
Out[156]: 5000

In [157]: t.hello(a=5)
Computing...
Out[157]: 5000

In [158]: t.hello(5)
Computing...
Out[158]: 5000

In [159]: t._hello
Out[159]: {(): 5000, (5,): 5000, (('a', 5),): 5000}
```

The result is computed 3 times, because the arguments are not given the same way (even if they are the "same" argument!).

Does someone know how I could catch the "default" values given to the function, inside the decorator?

Thank you

Comment: Do you know [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)?

Comment: @Jonas Wielicki It's not available in Python below 3.2. He's using Python 2.x

Comment: @VadimShkaberda right, I did not notice that it was added in 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be various solutions depending on how complicated will be arguments' structure of function. The solution I prefer is to add inner function into `hello`. If you don't want to change the name of your cache, give it the same name your outer function have:

```
class Test:
    def hello(self, a=5):
        @cache
        def hello(self, a):
            return 1000 * a
        return hello(self, a)

t = Test()
t.hello()
t.hello(a=5)
t.hello(5)
t._hello

Out[111]: Computing...
Already computed!
Already computed!
{(5,): 5000}
```

Another approach is to add check for default variables in decorator, for example:

```
def cache(func):
    name = "_{:s}".format(func.__name__)
    def wrapped(obj, *args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(obj, name) or getattr(obj, name) is None:
            setattr(obj, name, {})
        o = getattr(obj, name)
        a = args + tuple(kwargs.items())
        if func.func_defaults: # checking if func have default variable
            for k in kwargs.keys():
                if k in func.func_code.co_varnames and kwargs[k] == func.func_defaults[0]:
                    a = ()
            if args:
                if args[0] == func.func_defaults[0]:
                    a = ()
        if not a in o:
            print "Computing..."
            o[a] = func(obj, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print "Already computed!"
        return o[a]
    return wrapped

class Test:
    @cache
    def hello(self, a=5):
        return 1000 * a

t = Test()
t.hello()
t.hello(a=5)
t.hello(5)
t._hello

Out[112]: Computing...
Already computed!
Already computed!
{(): 5000}
```

If you'd have, e.g. 2 default variables, first code (with inner function) still would work, whereas the second one would need changes in "default variable check rules".

Comment: Thanks you for fast answer! I like both way, but I think I will chose the second one, which corresponds more to what I need!

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a sufficiently recent version of Python, you can use [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object) to get a `Signature` object that fully encapsulates the information about the function's arguments. Then you can call its `bind` method with the arguments your wrapper gets passed, to get a `BoundArguments` object. Call the `apply_defaults` method on the `BoundArguments` to fill in any missing arguments that have default values, and examine the `arguments` ordered dictionary to see an unambiguous listing of the parameters to the function and their values for this call:

```
import inspect

def cache(func):
    name = "_{:s}".format(func.__name__)
    sig = inspect.signature(func)
    def wrapped(obj, *args, **kwargs):
        cache_dict = getattr(obj, name, None)
        if cache_dict is None:
            cache_dict = {}
            setattr(obj, name, cache_dict)    
        bound_args = sig.bind(obj, *args, **kwargs)
        bound_args.apply_defaults()
        cache_key = tuple(bound_args.arguments.values())
        if not cache_key in cache_dict:
            print("Computing...")
            cache_dict[cache_key] = func(obj, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print("Already computed!")
        return cache_dict[cache_key]
    return wrapped
```

Note that I renamed your `a` and `o` variables to have more meaningful names. I also changed around the way the cache dictionary is set up on the object. Fewer `getattr` and `setattr` calls this way!

The `inspect.signature` function and associated types were added in Python 3.3, but the `apply_defaults` method on `BoundArguments` objects is new in Python 3.5. There's a backport of the basic functionality for older Python versions [on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcsigs), but it doesn't include `apply_defaults` yet, it seems. I'm going to report that as an issue on the backport's [github tracker](https://github.com/testing-cabal/funcsigs/issues).